# Rails 3: How to eager load an association AND apply a condition with includes()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, eager-loading

My app has `Question` models that `has_many` `UserResponse` models.

I'd like to get the last 5 questions that a particular `User` has answered with the associated `UserResponse` objects filtered on the `user_id` field.

Here's what I currently have:

```
Question.group("questions.id").
joins("inner join user_responses r on r.question_id = questions.id").
where("r.user_id = #{user_id}").
order("questions.id asc").limit(5)
```

This query gives me back what I want, but the problem is when I get a `Question` out of the array and do `question.user_responses` the result is all of the responses for that question, not just the ones that should be filtered by the join/where clause above.

I've tried to do this:

```
Question.includes(:user_responses).group("questions.id").
joins("inner join user_responses r on r.question_id = questions.id").
where("r.user_id = #{user_id}").
order("questions.id asc").limit(5)
```

thinking it would eager load each response...but it doesn't appear to function that way.

Where am I going wrong?

If it makes a difference, the reason I need everything eagerly loaded is because I want to take the array and call to_json on it and return the json from a web service for my mobile app, so I need the entire graph available.

Comment: Why are you attempting to group here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to get too complicated here. How about the following?

```
Question
  .includes(:user_responses)
  .where("user_id = ?", user_id)
  .order("questions.id asc")
  .limit(5)
```

Comment: yes, you are right.  I think the query used to be more complex and instead of just approaching the problem from scratch I tried to massage the old code.  Thank you so much for your quick and accurate response.

Comment: Should to mention that you have potential sql injection with user_id param. Of course you won't but it's stackoverflow and people will copy and paste this code, than change it and..
So better do this: where("r.user_id = ?", user_id).

Comment: For more information about sql injection see here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: `r` is undefined. Should be `user_responses.user_id` instead.

Comment: Good call. I think i can just be user_id though because it's a unambiguous.